# Django rest framework - return objects ordered by callable method result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

So basically the title says it all: how can I order the queryset that will be returned on the API by a callable method result that is not stored on the database?

This field is dynamic and depends on each user's request, hence it can't be stored anywhere.

I tried just using, which is what I want to achieve:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter('my_filters').order_by('my_method')
```

but it doesn't work since it has to be a column on the database.

I also tried:

```
queryset = sorted(Post.objects.filter('my_filters'), key=lambda x: x.my_method())
```

But it throws the "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'" error.

How can I sort the results of the queryset according to a method then? Any ideas?
I will also need to limit the number of responses to the top results calculated this way.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

'my_filters' in this case just checks a boolean property

```
.filter(active=True)
```

and my_method checks the time elapsed comparing with timezone.now():

```
def microseconds_elapsed(self):
    return getMicrosecondsElapsed(self.datetime)
```

where

```
def getMicrosecondsElapsed(datetime):  
    timedelta = timezone.now() - datetime  
    microseconds = 0  
    microseconds += timedelta.microseconds  
    microseconds += timedelta.seconds*1000000  
    microseconds += timedelta.days*86400000000  
    return microseconds
```

I've made some progress using annotate and PostgreSQL functions by using:

```
get_queryset().annotate(time_elapsed=Func(F('datetime'), function='age'))
```

but this results in a django error

> float() argument must be a string or a number

In this case I just need to get the number of microseconds elapsed from the datetime field stored in the object so I can proceed with another calculation.

Anybody knows what's going on and how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: provide 'my filters' and 'my method'. Without full code don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I don't recommend sorting data like that in large databases,

Comment: what is the function 'age'? Is it a django build it in function?

Comment: @zaphod100.10 age is a PostgreSQL function as described here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT